# When to register for location updates?

Tags: android, locationmanager, oncreate, onresume, locationlistener

I am writing an Android application that requires the user's current location. I register for location updates both from the network, and from GPS using the following code (locationManager is already defined):

```
    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates.
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gps_min_time),
            getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gps_min_dist), this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gps_min_time),
            getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gps_min_dist), this);
```

I currently have this code in `onCreate`, but in order to save power, I remove both listeners in `onPause` and add them both again in `onResume`.

When the application starts, it adds both listeners twice, once in `onCreate`, and once in `onResume`. I have two question about this:

1. Does having each listener added twice mean that it actually gets added twice, or does the second call have no effect?
2. Should I remove the `requestLocationUpdate`s from `onCreate` and just have them in `onResume` or should I remove all listeners first in `onResume` before adding them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your Listener will be added as a key to a Hashmap. So If you insert `this` (Your Activity) and don't override `equals` it should be overridden, and has no effect, because it is the SAME Listener.
2. Anyway, I would remove the register inside onCreate and just leave it inside onResume, as you will save at least the time to Hash your listener and the Method calls.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add them in `onResume()`. Create the manager in `onCreate()` and add and remove listeners in `onResume()` and `onPause()`.

I don't have an answer to your first question.

Comment: The answer to the first question can be [found in the source code](http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/blobs/56fe6be0c3e1eaa7d5d1ba96910008c504a6c362/services/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java)